# Retrieve WorldPay auth token via the Shopify API

Tags: shopify

We're using Shopify with WorldPay as a payment processor. Is there any way of getting the WorldPay authorization token for an order via the Shopify API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payment gateway info (aside from the name of the gateway) is excluded from the API, primarily for security reasons.